# Notifications Broken after app were updated with wrong google-service.json

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-services

We have an app that already published in Google Play

During the latest release, we have made a mistake and uploaded the app with the wrong google-service.json file.
On the next day, we have submitted a new one with correct google-service.json

**Problem**: Some of the users stop receiving PUSH notifications even they update the app to the latest version.

Any thoughts?

Comment: they need to clear cache of clear storage , and may need to reinstall application , also they may need to login again

Comment: Only re-installing help for now, but this is weird solution

Comment: Yes it is not the perfect solution , I know